# shopware category shows _cat_catid instead of the clear name

Tags: e-commerce, shopware

I have a problem with a shopware SEO category. I added a new one, identical to the working ones at least from what I can see (i just took that project from someone)
the difference tho instead of giving me out `/catgeory1/category2` the shop gives me `shop.de/catgeory2name_cat_catid.html` does someone know where this comes from?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Shopware does not make any URLs with .html unless you tell it Shopware to do it.

Second one: You have to rebuild category index after adding new categories in the performance module.